# $(window).height() returns strange value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dimensions

I tried following commands to determine the viewport height:

```
var H1 = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
    H2 = $(window).height();
```

The result is 8 in all cases. But the viewport is much bigger (> 500).

Supplement:

The difference is between

```
        H  = $(document).height()
        H1 = $(window).height()
```

with the Firefox-Browser (24.0/Debian). H = 600  H1 = 8 
With Chromium (29.0/Debian)   H = 600   H1 = 600

I don't know why.

Comment: What is the Question?

Comment: what is that `$win` ? And also post a live example of this occurring..

Comment: $win is define as $win = $(window);

Live example: http://www.lek2.de/2064/assets/

The code sample is in murbiks-animation-lib-0.0.1.js Line 650.

The problem is only with Firefox (24.0/Debian)

Answer (score 0):

Are there margins and padding?

Try `H2 = $(window).outerHeight(true)`

Comment: This returns a jQuery object as it seems, but not a number.

Answer (score 0):

If there are margins or paddings, you should look at `$(window).outerHeight()` .
More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)

Comment: It also returns 8.

W  = $win.outerWidth(true)

returns 1647. The right value ...  ~:-|

Comment: The problem is only with Firefox (24.0/Debian)

Comment: I see yea, i did not notice. You could try this javascript function : `window.screen.availWidth` and for the height `window.screen.availHeight` I hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Note that .height() will always return the content height, regardless of the value of the CSS box-sizing property. As of jQuery 1.8, this may require retrieving the CSS height plus box-sizing property and then subtracting any potential border and padding on each element when the element has box-sizing: border-box. To avoid this penalty, use .css( "height" ) rather than .height().